# How to split 1 long paragraph to 2 shorter paragraphs? Google Document

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I want paragraphs to be up to 3 sentences only.

For that, my strategy is to loop on all paragraphs and find the 3rd sentence ending (see note). And then, to add a "\r" char after it.

**This is the code I have:**

```
for (var i = 1; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  ...
  sentEnds = paragraphs[i].getText().match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_\u0590-\u05fe][.?!](\s|$)|[.?!][.?!](\s|$)/g);
  //this array is used to count sentences in Hebrew/English/digits that end with 1 or more of either ".","?" or "!"
  ...
  if ((sentEnds != null) && (sentEnds.length > 3)) {
    lineBreakAnchor = paragraphs[i].getText().match(/.{10}[.?!](\s)/g);
    paragraphs[i].replaceText(lineBreakAnchor[2],lineBreakAnchor[2] + "\r");
  }
}
```

This works fine for round 1. But if I run the code again- **the text after the inserted "\r" char is not recognized as a new paragraph**. Hence, more "\r" (new lines) will be inserted each time the script is running.

How can I make the script "understand" that "\r" means new, separate paragraph?

**OR**

Is there another character/approach that will do the trick?

Thank you.

- Note: I use the last 10 characters of the sentence assuming the match will be unique enough to make only 1 replacement.

Comment: Try `\n` and see if there is `\n` in the actual document.

Comment: This doesn't change the described behavior

Comment: Did you see whether there is a `\n` in the doc? Try find and replace menu with regex on

Comment: I did. There is a match for `\n` at any paragraph end. However- even when I have the script add `\n` - these ones are not detected in the search...

Comment: there you have your answer. It seems it's not possible to split paragraphs by just regex.  You probably need to use clear current paragraph and use `.appendParagraph()` independently for each paragraph. [**Paragraphs may not contain new-line characters. New-line characters ("\n") are converted to line-break characters ("\r").**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph). Said otherwise, `\n` separates new paragraphs. If it's not possible to directly add `\n`, you need to  use inbuilt methods like `.append()`

Comment: .append adds a paragraph at the end of the document. How can the same locations be detected, but instead of the replace method- convert 1 paragraph into 2 in the middle of the document? This is actually kind of the original question

Comment: Try [insertParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-text) and [getChildIdx](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild) to get the correct index to insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying your own regex expression you can achieve this.

[image]

### Try this approach to split the paragraphs:

- Grab the whole content of the document and create an array of sentences.
- Insert paragraphs with up to 3 sentences after original paragraphs.
- Remove original paragraphs from hell.

```js
function sentenceMe() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  var sentences = [];
  // Split paragraphs into sentences
  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    var parText = paragraphs[i].getText();
    //Count sentences in Hebrew/English/digits that end with 1 or more of either ".","?" or "!"
    var sentEnds = parText.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9_\u0590-\u05fe][.?!](\s|$)|[.?!][.?!](\s|$)/g);
    if (sentEnds){
      for (var j=0; j< sentEnds.length; j++){
        var initIdx = 0;
        var sentence = parText.substring(initIdx,parText.indexOf(sentEnds[j])+3);
        var parInitIdx = initIdx;
        initIdx = parText.indexOf(sentEnds[j])+3;
        parText = parText.substring(initIdx - parInitIdx);
        sentences.push(sentence);
      }

    }
    // console.log(sentences);
  }

  inThrees(doc, paragraphs, sentences)
}

function inThrees(doc, paragraphs, sentences) {
  // define offset
  var offset = paragraphs.length;
  // Create paragraphs with up to 3 sentences
  var k=0;
  do {
    var parText = sentences.splice(0,3).join(' ');
    doc.getBody().insertParagraph(k + offset  , parText.concat('\n'));
    k++
  }
  while (sentences.length > 0)

    // Remove paragraphs from hell
    for (var i = 0; i < offset; i++){
      doc.getBody().removeChild(paragraphs[i]);
    }
}
```

---

In case you are wondering about the custom menu, here is it:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem("3's the magic number", 'sentenceMe')
  .addToUi();
}
```

---

#### References:

- [DocumentApp.Body.insertParagraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex,-text)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the detection of sentences is not an easy task.

- A sentence does not always end with a dot, a question mark or an exclamation mark. If the sentence ends with a quote then punctuation rules in some countries force you to put the end of the sentence mark inside the quote:

  > John asked: "Who's there?"
- Not every dot means an end of a sentence, usually the dot after an uppercase letter does not end the sentence, because it occurs after an initial. The sentence does not end after `J.` here:

  > The latest Star Wars movie has been directed by J.J. Abrams.
- However, sometimes the sentence *does* end after a capital letter followed by a dot:

  > This project has been sponsored by NASA.
- And abbreviations can make it very hard:

  > For more information check the article in Phys. Rev. Letters 66, 2697, 2013.

Having in mind these difficulties let's still try to get some expression which will work in "usual" cases.

Make a global match and substitution. Match

```
((?:[^.?!]+[.?!] +){3})
```

and substitute it with

```
\1\r
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOvJQn/1)

This looks for 3 sentences (a sentence is a sequence of not-dot, not-?, not-! characters followed by a dot, a ? or a ! and some spaces) and puts a \r after them.

**UPDATED 2020-03-04**

Try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp('((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\\u0590-\\u05fe\\s]+[.?!]+\\s+){3})', 'gi');
for (var i = 1; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
  paragraphs[i].replaceText(regex, '$1\\r');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. However, not sure how to implement your idea in the code. I will share some more of my code to elaborate what is enough for me to pass as a sentence.

Comment: Updated answer. I suppose paragraphs contain a list of text fields, each of which contain multiple paragraphs.

Comment: I get this:Exception: Invalid regular expression pattern /((?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\u0590-\u05fe\s]+[.?!]+\s+){3})/giDetails

Comment: Also, I am not sure that the alternate approach for detecting the location of a new line solves the actual issue here (that the script adds new line, but doesn’t treat it as a paragraph separation)